# Google Maps MeasureTool in React - measuring line disappears after zoom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

React app uses [measuretool-googlemaps-v3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/measuretool-googlemaps-v3):

```
import {MapControl} from 'google-react-maps'
import MeasureTool from 'measuretool-googlemaps-v3/lib/MeasureTool'
```

MeasureTool construction:

```
  createMeasureTool() {

    this.measureTool = new MeasureTool(this.props.map, {
      showSegmentLength: false,
      tooltip: false,
      contextMenu: false
    })
    this.measureTool._helper.formatLength = function(value) {
      return this._formatLengthMetric(value) + " / " + this._formatLengthImperial(value * 3.28084)
    }
  }
```

Measuring works well until user does zoom in or zoom out on a map. Then measuring line disappears and it is necessary to recreate MeasureTool instance to use measuring function again. Map/MeasureTool/MapControl are not rerendered during zoom.

How to retain measuring line after zoom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated `google-react-maps` from `^1.1.26` to `^1.2.26`, added `google-maps-api": "^2.0.1` and it solved the problem.